# How to draw line on Image Pattern exactly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, cashapelayer

I have a UIImageView. Inside that I am drawing a line wit user touch event. Problem is that a line can be drawn anywhere in `UIImageview`, but I like to draw line with image pattern only.

For example, look at this image. I need to draw line on image pattern only.

[image]

*This is my code:*

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.imgColor];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];
    startingPoint=touchPoint;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.imgColor.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [arrLayer addObject:shapeLayer];
    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);



}
```

I hope some one solve my problem.

Comment: subclass the uiview and draw the image on it instead of using imageview.

Comment: @Mr.T can you explain it clearly

Comment: sorry, are you saying that the line should only be drawn on the pattern? IF you move your finger away from the pattern then the line should not be drawn. IS that waht u r saying ?

Comment: Masking what's outside is not enough?

Comment: Finally i get answer from here :) [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736949/how-to-find-out-uncoloured-area-uibeizerpath)

Answer (score 8):

You can try this way.

Let's say you have a `bezierPath` called `maskPath`,in my case it is `textPath` which is used to mask the `imageView`.

I am using a simple `maskView` which draws letter Q on `imageView`.

Adding the `maskPath`: (Adds a simple Q shaped mask to the imageView)

```
-(void)applyMask{

//// Text Drawing
textPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[textPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(181, 179.8)];
[textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(166, 197.2)];
[textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(189.7, 216.1)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(160, 222.1) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(180.1, 220.1) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(170.2, 222.1)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(126.4, 214.45) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(147, 222.1) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(135.8, 219.55)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(103.3, 194.2) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(117, 209.35) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(109.3, 202.6)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(90.1, 165.85) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(97.3, 185.8) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(92.9, 176.35)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(85.9, 133.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(87.3, 155.35) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(85.9, 144.7)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(90.1, 101.95) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(85.9, 123.1) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(87.3, 112.45)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(103.3, 73.6) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(92.9, 91.45) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(97.3, 82)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(126.4, 53.35) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(109.3, 65.2) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(117, 58.45)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(160, 45.7) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(135.8, 48.25) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(147, 45.7)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(193.6, 53.35) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(173, 45.7) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(184.2, 48.25)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(216.7, 73.6) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(203, 58.45) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(210.7, 65.2)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(229.9, 101.95) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(222.7, 82) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(227.1, 91.45)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(234.1, 133.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(232.7, 112.45) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(234.1, 123.1)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(228.1, 171.85) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(234.1, 147.1) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(232.1, 159.75)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(209.5, 202.6) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(224.1, 183.95) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(217.9, 194.2)];
[textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(181, 179.8)];
[textPath closePath];
[textPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(244, 259.3)];
[textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(258.4, 241.3)];
[textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(230.2, 219.1)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(254.5, 180.7) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(241, 208.3) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(249.1, 195.5)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(262.6, 133.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(259.9, 165.9) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(262.6, 150.3)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(256.15, 91.75) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(262.6, 119.3) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(260.45, 105.25)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(236.8, 55.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(251.85, 78.25) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(245.4, 66.3)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(204.7, 31) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(228.2, 45.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(217.5, 37.2)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(160, 21.7) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(191.9, 24.8) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(177, 21.7)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(115.3, 31) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(143, 21.7) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(128.1, 24.8)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(83.2, 55.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(102.5, 37.2) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(91.8, 45.5)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(63.85, 91.75) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(74.6, 66.3) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(68.15, 78.25)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(57.4, 133.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(59.55, 105.25) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(57.4, 119.3)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(63.85, 176.05) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(57.4, 148.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(59.55, 162.55)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(83.2, 211.9) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(68.15, 189.55) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(74.6, 201.5)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(115.3, 236.65) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(91.8, 222.3) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(102.5, 230.55)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(160, 245.8) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(128.1, 242.75) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(143, 245.8)];
[textPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(211.3, 233.2) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(179.8, 245.8) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(196.9, 241.6)];
[textPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(244, 259.3)];
[textPath closePath];
[UIColor.blackColor setFill];
[textPath fill];

maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [textPath CGPath];
maskLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
[self.imgView.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];

}
```

You already have the method:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.imgView];

        if ([textPath containsPoint:touchPoint]) {
            path=nil; //this is not need,unless u want to start a new path everytime this condition executes.
            path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
            [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
            [path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(_startingPoint.x,_startingPoint.y)];
            _startingPoint=touchPoint;

        drawLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        drawLayer.path = [path CGPath];
        drawLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        drawLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
        drawLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        [self.imgView.layer addSublayer:drawLayer];
        NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);

        }
}
```

You can now verify , if the touch point is in the `textPath` whcih is a `bezierPath`.
If the touchPoint is in the `textPath`, then allow the draw, else dont draw.

The result will be something like this:

[image]

As you see, this code will allow you to draw only in the masked path.
If you want to draw outside of the `textPath`, then you can do simply:

```
  if (![textPath containsPoint:touchPoint]) {
 path=nil; //this is not need,unless u want to start a new path everytime this condition executes.
 path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_startingPoint.x,_startingPoint.y)];
_startingPoint=touchPoint;

    drawLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    drawLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    drawLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    drawLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    drawLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.imgView.layer addSublayer:drawLayer];
    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);


}
```

**Note:** You need to take care of your touches moved method in drawing the line. As the bezier path method `addLineToPoint` will add line to the touchPoint and this line may cross the maskedPath. You need to make sure you are close the previosu bezier path and start a new one to avoid the lines to be drawn on the outside part of masked area.

Comment: but the image is not static here ,then how i have to calculate the uibezierPath .

Comment: What Image ? In your case, are you talking about the I shaped mask ?

Comment: yes brother for me that image is not static ,then how i have to calculate the uibeizerPath path ....

Comment: How are you drawing the I on imageview ? Is it an image or is it a mask ?

Comment: its a image only @mr.t

Comment: IT would be very complex to detect the touch on certain color pattern on the image. You need to have a bezier path drawn as a mask to the imageView. Try creating the mask shape using bezier path.If you want the I shaped mask, I can draw it for u.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100390/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-mr-t).

Comment: Yeah I did. Check ur spam or other folder .  Or send a hi msg to my email tejanvm@gmail.com, I will reply back

Comment: may be it will helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736949/how-to-find-out-uncoloured-area-uibeizerpath/34739531#34739531 ,but i didn't receive your mail ,i send invitation to you .please refer that answer and tell me what was going on that code only 50% i understood .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are you trying to display alphabets in some language, may be you can use that language font for dynamic display. Just a thought. Together with the logic mentioned above you can try this.

Comment: that grey colour part is the uiimageview ,that white color part is the image ,is there any way to find out the uncolored cgrectpoints